# How do I migrate file uploads?

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm working on a custom migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8. Some of the content types have a field used for file attachments (*field_attachments*).

When I run the migration that connects the files to the nodes, I get this error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, status, uid, title, created, changed, promote, sticky, default_langcode, revision_translation_affected) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 2064 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 3019 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => forum [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1558576761 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 1558576761 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 1 ) (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:847)

The *migrate_plus.migration.custom_upload.yml* file for the migration contains the following lines.

```yaml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: custom_upload
class: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration
field_plugin_method: alterFieldInstanceMigration
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 6'
  - Content
migration_group: custom
label: 'File uploads'
source:
  plugin: d6_upload
process:
  nid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: nid
  vid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: vid
  langcode:
    -
      plugin: user_langcode
      source: language
      fallback_to_site_default: true
  type:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: type
  field_attachments:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: upload
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: migration_lookup
          migration: custom_file
          source: fid
        display:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: 1
        description: description
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - custom_file
    - custom_article
    - custom_forum
```

From the error message, it appears that Drupal is trying to create a node; even though, I'm actually running the *custom_upload* migration after I ran the migration of all nodes.

I have migrated the nodes and the files already and I can see all the nodes in the database as well as the files in their directory and the database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Your `custom_upload` migration *is* trying to create nodes; the `custom_upload` migration is taking a `d6_upload` [source plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21d6%21Upload.php/class/Upload/8.7.x):

```
source:
  plugin: d6_upload
```

...and mapping it to a `node:entity` [destination plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21destination%21Entity.php/class/Entity/8.7.x):

```
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
```

Since the `d6_upload` source doesn't have a `title` field to map to the `node:entity` field in the `process` definition of your migration, the migration fails as it tries to insert a titleless node.

You need update your node migration. If your node/file migrations are working, the node migration should have a 
`process.field_attachments` yml property to map `field_attachments.target_id` to the `fid` property from your `custom_file` migration.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thank you for answering. You're helping me see the light at the end, but I'm not getting it quite yet.

Comment: I can confirm that the node and file migrations are working.
The YAML file above, is basically a slightly modified copy of core/modules/file/migrations/d6_upload.yml
I expected that `plugin: 'entity:node'` would update the node entity (not create a new one) because the same file has a `field_attachments` that uses a `plugin: sub_process`.
You mentioned that the node migration should have a  `process.field_attachments` yml property. How would that look like? That's where I'm still lost. Do you have a snippet of code or could you point me somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Every content type migration creates its own mapping table.

I got a clue from how the taxonomy terms are migrated. The trick was to tell Drupal where to look for the `nid`.

I replaced:

```
process:
  nid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: nid
  vid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: vid
```

with...

```
process:
  nid:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration:
        - custom_article
        - custom_forum
      source: nid
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
```

... and now it works.

By listing the internal names of my two content types, Drupal was able to figure out what node mapping table should be used.

Note that I removed the `vid:` block with the replacement. I'm not importing node revisions and therefore, I'm not expecting that this will affect anything in my case.